# Oracle trigger is being called, but nothing happens

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g, exception, triggers

I have a **AFTER INSERT TRIGGER** which in turn calls a procedure. Trigger and procedure are logging to the table DEVLOGS properly, no exception seems to occur.

My **TRIGGER**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MYSCHEMA.MYTRIGGER
AFTER INSERT ON MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE err_msg varchar(1000);
BEGIN

-- Log start trigger
    INSERT INTO DEVLOGS (TIMESTAMP, MSG  ) values ( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'Now starting TRIGGER MYTRIGGER' );

-- CALL Procedure:
    MYSCHEMA.MYPROC(
            :NEW.MNPDID, 
            NVL(:NEW.CTCAETERM,'NULL'), 
            NVL(:NEW.SO_NARRATIVE || :NEW.SO_NARRATIVE1 || :NEW.SO_NARRATIVE2,'NULL'), 
            NVL(:NEW.SO_TRUE,1),
            NVL(:NEW.ADDINFO,'NULL'), 
            NVL(:NEW.SO_REL1,0), 
            NVL(:NEW.SO_REL2,0), 
            NVL(:NEW.SO_SOC1,'NULL')
         );

-- Log end trigger
    INSERT INTO DEVLOGS (TIMESTAMP, MNPDID, MSG  ) values ( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, :NEW.MNPDID, 'OK TRIGGER MYTRIGGER(' || 
            :NEW.MNPDID                     || ', ' || 
            NVL(:NEW.CTCAETERM,'NULL')      || ', ' ||
            NVL(:NEW.SO_NARRATIVE || :NEW.SO_NARRATIVE1 || :NEW.SO_NARRATIVE2,'NULL')   || ', ' ||
            NVL(:NEW.SO_TRUE,1)         || ', ' ||
            NVL(:NEW.ADDINFO,'NULL')      || ', ' ||
            NVL(:NEW.SO_REL1,0)         || ', ' ||
            NVL(:NEW.SO_REL2,0)         || ', ' ||
            NVL(:NEW.SO_SOC1,'NULL')      || '). Terminated, no exception' );

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    err_msg := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 1000);
    INSERT INTO DEVLOGS (TIMESTAMP, MSG  ) values ( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'ERROR IN TRIGGER MYTRIGGER:' || err_msg );
END;
/
```

My PROCEDURE

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY MYSCHEMA.MYPACKAGE AS
PROCEDURE MYPROC(
    ID DEVSAES.MNPDID%TYPE,
    CTCAETERM DEVSAES.CTCAETERM%TYPE , 
    SO_NARRATIVE DEVSAES.SO_NARRATIVE%TYPE, 
    SO_TRUE DEVSAES.TRUESAE%TYPE,
    ADDINFO DEVSAES.ADDINFO%TYPE, 
    SO_REL1 DEVSAES.SO_REL1%TYPE, 
    SO_REL2 DEVSAES.SO_REL2%TYPE, 
    SO_SOC1 DEVSAES.SO_SOC1%TYPE)
IS
err_msg varchar2(1000);
BEGIN

INSERT INTO DEVLOGS (TIMESTAMP, MSG  ) values ( current_timestamp, 'In PROCEDURE MYPROC: Now calling procedure with params: ' || ID || ', ' || CTCAETERM || ', ' || SO_NARRATIVE || ', ' || SO_TRUE || ', ' || ADDINFO || ', ' || SO_REL1 || ', ' || SO_REL2 || ', ' || SO_SOC1 );
INSERT INTO DEVSAES
SELECT
   CN.PID
  ,AE.AEDATE
  ,AE.AEID
  ,ID
...
FROM TABLE1 CN
INNER JOIN TABLE2 AE
   ON CN.CNID = AE.CNID

...
WHERE AE.MNPDID = ID;

INSERT INTO DEVLOGS (TIMESTAMP, MSG  ) values ( current_timestamp, 'In PROCEDURE MYPROC: Procedure terminated.');
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    err_msg := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 1000);
    INSERT INTO DEVLOGS (TIMESTAMP, MSG  ) values ( current_timestamp, 'In PROCEDURE MYPROC:' || err_msg );
END;
END MYPACKAGE;
/
```

Now when looking into the logs, no exception is being raised:

```
14/03/2016 08:15:45.367522        Now startting TRIGGER MYTRIGGER
14/03/2016 08:15:45.673051              In PROCEDURE MYPROC: Now calling procedure with params: 998, Cataract, NULL, 1, NULL, 2, 4, Eye disorders
14/03/2016 08:15:46.910680              In PROCEDURE MYPROC: Procedure terminated.
14/03/2016 08:15:46.915188  998     OK TRIGGER MYTRIGGER(998, Cataract, NULL, 1, NULL, 2, 4, Eye disorders). Terminated, no exception
```

No data is being found in the table **DEVSAES** where the procedure actually should write to, and moreover, when I call the procedure 'manually' (i.e. without the trigger before), **then the values are inserted properly**!

**UPDATE**

I have now joined the procedure into the trigger. Further improvements are done:

- `PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS TRANSACTION` added
- `COMMIT`added at the end
- Logging the `SQL%Rowcount` into DEVLOGS. It indeed says `0 rows
  inserted`.

When I call the SELECT part of the query and replace the :NEW variable with a fixed value (to simulate the inserted parameters), it returns me one row, exactly the one which I like to insert automatically into the DEVSAES table.

My modified query looks like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MYSCHEMA.MYTRIGGER
AFTER INSERT
ON MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
    err_msg varchar(1000);
    v_count integer;
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
INSERT INTO DEVLOGS (TIMESTAMP, MSG) values ( current_timestamp,
    'In Trigger MYTRIGGER: Now calling INSERT with params: ' || :NEW.MNPDID || ', ' || :NEW.CTCAETERM );
INSERT INTO DEVSAES
SELECT
   CN.PID
  ,AE.AEDATE
  ,AE.AEID
  ,:NEW.ID
  ,:NEW.CTCAETERM

...

FROM MYSCHEMA.CASENODE CN
  INNER JOIN MYSCHEMA.ADVERSEEVENT AE
     ON CN.CNID = AE.CNID
...
WHERE D2.MNPDID = :NEW.MNPDID;
v_count := SQL%ROWCOUNT;
INSERT INTO DEVLOGS (TIMESTAMP, MSG  ) VALUES ( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'Trigger MYSCHEMA.MYTRIGGER terminated. No exceptions catched. ' || v_count ||' rows inserted. Now comitting.');
COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    err_msg := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 1000);
    INSERT INTO DEVLOGS (TIMESTAMP, MSG  ) VALUES ( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'ERROR IN TRIGGER MYTRIGGER:' || err_msg );
END;
/
```

The log :

```
17/03/2016 14:05:51.664756              Trigger MYSCHEMA.MYTRIGGER terminated. No exceptions catched. 0 rows inserted. Now comitting.
17/03/2016 14:05:51.664153              In TRIGGER MYTRIGGER: Now calling INSERT with params: 1056, Cushingoid, , , , 2, 3, Endocrine disorders
```

Comment: Try to use `SQL%ROWCOUNT` to check if your insert from select to DEVSAES works

Comment: Did you `COMMIT` the inserts in the procedure/trigger?

Comment: Why use a trigger at all? Create a procedure that encapsulates all the logic of the trigger and the insert it triggers off of and then instead of using an insert just call the procedure.

Comment: Your problem is here:WHERE D2.MNPDID = ID; your table probably has a column called ID so the procedure parameter isn't being used.

Comment: logging procedures should also use the PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS TRANSACTION so the logging happens regardless of any actions or other faults.  Does yours?

Comment: @Maheswaran: In TRIGGER MYTRIGGER:ORA-04092: cannot COMMIT in a trigger, even when it's in the procedure called by the trigger

Comment: @MT0: That's what I did in the beginning, but for debugging reasons, I separated trigger and procedure. Therefore I was able to call the procedure manually, which worked fine. After trigger and procedure work, I'll 'merge' them together again.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution: In my procedure, there was missing a column which was set **NOT NULL** in the destination table.
What I did:

- I added this missing column to the INSERT statement
- then I had to
  remove the `insert into DEVLOGS`, the `AUTONOMOUS TRANSACTION` as
  well as the `COMMIT` statements I inserted in the UPDATE section above.

However, I got no idea why the not NULL constraint violation wasn't catched by my exception handler in the procedure/trigger.

The oracle still is not very predictive to me...